# Best way to represent a UUID in Avro?

Tags: uuid, avro

I am curious to understand the best practice for encoding one very specific type of data within Avro: UUIDs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far, the only way I found is defining a custom UUID:

```
{
  "namespace" : "your.namespace",
  "type" : "fixed",
  "name" : "UUID",
  "size" : 16
}
```

I'm using Scala, so I also defined an implicit conversion between `java.util.UUID` and my custom UUID, so it's not that much of a hassle to use it.

Comment: Hello Marius. Could you post a small code example for the conversion?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I've been doing it:

```js
{
    "name": "user_id",
    "type": "string",
    "logicalType": "UUID"
}
```

At the time of writing the `logicalType` for UUIDs is not documented but it is nonetheless supported, you can check the code here and verify so yourself: https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/branch-1.8/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/LogicalTypes.java#L71

And here the docs: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.0/spec.html#UUID

Comment: It's now mentioned in the docs https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.0/spec.html#UUID

Comment: I think, it should be `"logicalType": "uuid"` with lowercase. The section of the documentation says `UUID`, but then notes `uuid`. Same for the `Date`, which has an example using `date`. It's also in the lowercase in the `LogicalTypes.java`.

Comment: @Francesco this is wrong. Not only it's `uuid` and not UUID, but also what you showed is element definition. Logical type goes into type definition. so you need to have it as: `"type": {"type": "string", "logicalType": "uuid"}` what you have will probably work in c++, but will produce warning in java and will be ignored. (try it out).

Answer (score 2):

I had to create a custom converter as I couldn't get the UUID logicalType working in my project on version 1.8.  Only took 2 steps --

1) Created a new class as below -

```
public class UUIDCustomConverter extends CustomEncoding<UUID>  {


@Override
protected void write(Object datum, Encoder out) throws IOException {

    out.writeString(((UUID)datum).toString());

}

@Override
protected UUID read(Object reuse, Decoder in) throws IOException {

    return UUID.fromString(in.readString());
}

}
```

2) Added the following annotation to the UUID property

```
//annotation for handling custom converter
@AvroEncode(using=UUIDCustomConverter.class)
protected UUID id;
```